# Converting Images to a data frame for cluster analysis

Tags: r

I'm attempting to convert a list of images to a data frame to run cluster analyses using diana and agnes, which require data be in the form of a matrix or data frame. I run the following code and the first two lines work fine, but I receive the following error every time.

```
x2012 <- list.files(path = 'Filepath/2012', pattern = "*.jpg", full.names=TRUE)
x2012_EH <- lapply(x2012, load.image)
eggs2012 <- as.data.frame(x2012_EH)
head(eggs2012)
```

Error in pixel.grid(x, ...) : unused argument (optional = TRUE)

I don't understand what this error is indicating.

Comment: What packages are you using? There is no `load.image` function in base R. What does `traceback()` show after you get the error?

Comment: I'm using the package imager. I

Comment: I've put the traceback here. 
Error in pixel.grid(x, ...) : unused argument (optional = TRUE)
6.as.data.frame.cimg(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
5.as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
4.(function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, fix.empty.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()) { data.row.names <- if (check.rows && is.null(row.names)) ...
3.do.call(data.frame, c(x, alis))
2.as.data.frame.list(x2012_EH)
1.as.data.frame(x2012_EH)

Comment: Looks like `load.image` creates a four-dimensional array (a `cimg` object) and `lapply` creates a list of these objects. I suspect you need to use `as.data.frame.cimg` first to create a list of data frames. Cluster analysis compares pairs of rows of data so each image needs to be represented as a single row.